# Rosbag API C++ Reading and writing bag

Tags: rosbag, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've been trying for a while to write a script that reads a bag file and modifies it at the same time, but seems it's impossible with the C++ API.
Does anyone know how to do this, or if there is the possibility to create a new bag file?
The only way I can do what I want is having two copies of the bag. One for reading and the other one for writing on it...There must be a smarter way!

Thanks!

Josep

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45433/rosbag-api-c++-reading-and-writing-bag/) by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my personal opinion, not allowing to change an existing bag is the smartest possible way because implementing the functionality to change existing bags is hard to get right. You needed to add synchronization (what if another program is reading from that bag at the same time), you needed to get the index and the stored topic headers right, ...

I think the best solution is really to read from one bag file and write to a new one.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2